# construction of state machine in string maching in book algorithm by CLRS

Tags: string, algorithm, clrs

Below is text from Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS. Below is code snippet in string matching using finite state automata. Trnstion function is used to construct state table with pattern to be searched.

Computing the transition function:
The following procedure computes the transition function sigma from a given pattern
P [1: :m].

```
COMPUTE-TRANSITION-FUNCTION.
1   m = P:length
2   for q = 0 to m
3      for each character a belongs to alphabetset
4         k = min (m + 1, q + 2)
5         repeat
6           k = k - 1
7         until Pk is suffix Pqa
8         sigma(q, a) = k
9 return sigma
```

This procedure computes sigma(q, a) in a straightforward manner according to its definition
in equation (32.4). The nested loops beginning on lines 2 and 3 consider all states q and all characters a,
and lines 4–8 set sigma(q, a) to be the largest k such
that Pk is suffix Pqa. The code starts with the largest conceivable value of k, which is
min(m, q+1). It then decreases k until Pk is suffix Pqa, which must eventually occur,since P0 is empty string which 
is a suffix of every string.

My questions on above code

1. Why author is selecting k as min(m + 1, q+2) at line 4?
2. In below explantion text author is mentions that "The code starts with the largest conceivable value of k, which is
   min(m, q+1)." Which is not matching with pseudo code above at line 4?

Request to explain with simple example and steps of psudoe code while answering above questions.

Comment: Just guessing here, but could it be that he has to initialize at `+1` because of the repeat-until structure? `k` is decremented before its first use.

Comment: @ VincentvanderWeele: You are right but I am finding difficult why we are taking min of one of these what is logic behind. Thanks